# How to get all keys and values of an array using array functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, find, maps

Using this array

```
const university = [
  { Students: 4, Lecturers: 15, Faculty: 'Mathematics' },
  { Students: 4, Lecturers: 15, Faculty: 'English' },
  { Students: 4, Lecturers: 15, Faculty: 'Science'} 
]
```

I want to return all values with a certain key:

```
const students = [
  { Students: 4 },
  { Students: 4 },
  { Students: 4 }
]
```

I know I can do this with a for in loop:

```
for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve this with `map`, `filter`, `find` or `reduce`? I can not seem to get the key out

Answer:

```
university.map(data => `Students: ${data.Students}`);
```

You could extract to a function.

```
getByKey(arr, val) {
    arr.map(data => `${val}: ${data[val]}`);
}


getKey(university, Faculty)
```

Comment: `university.map(({ Students }) => Students)`? or `university.map(obj => obj[key])`?

Comment: what is your key ? the value `4` ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - this is what I had it just returns the value.

Comment: @MisterJojo the key is 'Students'

Comment: Ah yes. Then return an object? `university.map(obj => { [key]: obj[key] })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key in that case is Students. So, you can do a map and return a new object with just that key.

```js
const university = [{
  Students: 46,
  Lecturers: 2,
  Faculty: 'Mathematics'
}, {
  Students: 65,
  Lecturers: 6,
  Faculty: 'English'
}, {
  Students: 48,
  Lecturers: 4,
  Faculty: 'Science'
}]

let result = [];

result = university.map(obj => {
  return {
    Students: obj.Students
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `map` and inside `map` you can pass keys in array(which you want to pick) and take `fromEntries` to form the object.

```js
const university = 
  [ { Students: 4, Lecturers: 15, Faculty: 'Mathematics' }, { Students: 4,Lecturers: 15, Faculty: 'English'} , { Students: 4, Lecturers: 15, Faculty: 'Science' } ];
  
const getGivenKeys=(arr,keys)=> arr.map(o=>Object.fromEntries(keys.map(k=>[k,o[k]])));

console.log(getGivenKeys(university, ['Students', 'Faculty']));
console.log(getGivenKeys(university, ['Students']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map() with a clean solution:

```js
const students = university.map(function(r){
    return {"Students" : r.Students};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` function, but without `return` keyword:

```js
university.map(uni=>({Students:uni.Students}));
```